# How to extract byte array from a JSON array of key:value pairs

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Within a web service I have converted a Word doc stored in a list item to a byte array using:

document.Bytes = item.File.OpenBinary();

then combined it with some other data to produce the follow JSON output:

```
{"Bytes":[208,207,17,224,161,177,26,225,0,0,0,0,0,etc., etc.],"Status":"Pending","Title":"Handbook","Version":"1"}
```

At the receiving end I want to extract the Word document. This is the code I am currently using to attempt to extract the byte array, but just cannot get it to work. It must be that I am on completely the wrong track here.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to approach this? It seemed a simple issue at first but has consumed hours of my time!

Note: In code below GetDoc(url) calls the web service that produces the JSON

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public byte[] GetJSONBytes(string url)
{   
    string ReturnJSON = GetDoc(url);  
    var objects = JArray.Parse(ReturnJSON); // parse as array  
    foreach (JObject root in objects)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
            {
                var appKey = app.Key;
                if (appKey == "Bytes")
                {
                    return (byte[])(app.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When it hits the line:

return (byte[])(app.Value);

I get the following error message:

System.ArgumentException: 'Can not convert Array to byte array.'

Comment: Why won't you use C# object to do that?

Comment: Can you expand?

Comment: You can create C# object that resembles the structure of your JSON and use `JsonConverter.DeserializeJson<T>(string)` to deserialize given JSON string to C# object. That way it's not only easier to access your byte array by just pointing to object's property, but is also way safer than going through JTokens.

Comment: I have tried something similar but was unable to extract the JSON representing the Word document as a string from the JSON, hence I tried the above method. I know I must be missing something obvious but have hit a dead end at the moment.

Comment: Dominik - You were right! I was using the incorrect object model for the JSON. Once I used the correct model I was able to extract the bytes OK. Thanks for prompting me to look again at it.